# Jekyll custom homepage

Tags: jekyll

I created a new jekyll project in line with the tutorial from docs. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/

I want to override the homepage of my project. I created an index.html file in the root of my project but when I run `jekyll build` I got an error:

```
Run in verbose mode to see all warnings.
          Conflict: The following destination is shared by multiple files.
                    The written file may end up with unexpected contents.
                    /home/aga/Work/website-jekyll/_site/index.html
                     - index.markdown
                     - /home/aga/Work/website-jekyll/index.html
                    
                    done in 0.403 seconds.
```

Despite this warning I run `jekyll serve` and got the correct site. But then when I change anything in my index.md or index.html and hit safe, and refresh the page, it goes back to the default one. I need to run the `jekyll build` and `jekyll serve` again. Is that expected? Feels weird. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message indicates that in your Jekyll project two index files exists: `index.md` and `index.html`, which is incorrect as they can override each other. Try to remove one of them and use only one as the main index file.

Also, if you follow the steps listed on [Quickstart](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) Jekyll tutorial page and generate new project with `jekyll new myblog`, then you should skip the [Setup](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/) step from the step-by-step tutorial (because you already have a basic setup thanks to `jekyll new` command).